# Python multiprocessing: Running a process after its parent exited

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm writing a Python program that runs under Mac OS and Linux, and I want to run some logic in a `multiprocessing.Process`. That logic will take a while, and I want it to continue running even after my program is finished and has exited. i.e., I want the main process to *not* wait for the auxiliary process to finish. I want the main process to exit as soon as it's finished.

I made a few experiments, and it seems that this behavior is the default when using `subprocess`, but I can't make it happen using `multiprocessing.Process`, even when I run `set_start_method('spawn')`.

Do you know of a way to get `multiprocessing.Process` to behave this way?

Comment: Did you look at the `daemon` flag.  I think setting this to `True` will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like starting a new process, and then calling os.fork from it does the trick.